# Count consecutive True (or 1) values in a Boolean (or numeric) column with Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I am hoping to count consecutive values in a column, preferably using Polars expressions.

```py
import polars
df = pl.DataFrame(
   {"values": [True,True,True,False,False,True,False,False,True,True]}
)
```

With the example data frame above, I would like to count the number of consecutive True values.

Below is example output using R's Data.Table package.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(value = c(T,T,T,F,F,T,F,F,T,T))
dt[, value2 := fifelse((1:.N) == .N & value == 1, .N, NA_integer_), by = rleid(value)]
dt
```

| value | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | 3 |
| FALSE | NA |
| FALSE | NA |
| TRUE | 1 |
| FALSE | NA |
| FALSE | NA |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | 2 |

Any ideas who this would be done efficiently using Polars?

**[EDIT with a new approach]**

I got it working with the code below, but hoping there is a more efficient way. Anyone know the default struct/dictionary field names from value_counts?

```py
(
    df.lazy()
    .with_row_count()
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("value") == False).then(
            pl.col("row_nr")
            
        ).fill_null(
            strategy = "forward"
        ).alias("id_consecutive_Trues")
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col("id_consecutive_Trues").value_counts(sort = True)
    )
    .with_column(
        (
            pl.col("id_consecutive_Trues").arr.eval(
                pl.element().struct().rename_fields(["value", "count"]).struct.field("count")
            ).arr.max()
            - pl.lit(1)
        ).alias("max_consecutive_true_values")
    )
    .collect()
)
```

Comment: The `.value_counts` field names are the name of what you're counting and `counts` so `id_consecutive_Trues` and `counts` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible definition of the problem is:

- On the last row of each `true` group, give me the group length.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("values") & pl.col("values").is_last())
     .then(pl.count())
     .over(pl.col("values").rle_id())
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ values ┆ count │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ bool   ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ true   ┆ null  │
│ true   ┆ null  │
│ true   ┆ 3     │
│ false  ┆ null  │
│ false  ┆ null  │
│ true   ┆ 1     │
│ false  ┆ null  │
│ false  ┆ null  │
│ true   ┆ null  │
│ true   ┆ 2     │
└────────┴───────┘
```

[`.rle_id()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html) gives us "group ids" for the consecutive values.

```py
df.with_columns(group = pl.col("values").rle_id())
```

```py
shape: (10, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ values ┆ group │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ bool   ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ true   ┆ 0     │
│ true   ┆ 0     │
│ true   ┆ 0     │
│ false  ┆ 1     │
│ false  ┆ 1     │
│ true   ┆ 2     │
│ false  ┆ 3     │
│ false  ┆ 3     │
│ true   ┆ 4     │
│ true   ┆ 4     │
└────────┴───────┘
```

[`.is_last()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_last.html) with the `.over()` allows us to detect the last row of each group.

[`pl.count()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.count.html#polars.count) with `.over()` gives us the number of rows in the group.

Comment: Thanks! I thought to use shift, but figured it would be too expensive. Any insight into whether your solution would be more performant than approach? I will benchmark both. Thank you again for the quick response!

Comment: I would think it's more performant as it seems to be doing less work than your example - but I could be wrong. If you're using `.arr.eval` you can try adding [`parallel=True`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.eval.html#polars.Expr.arr.eval) to see if it makes a difference in your benchmark.